# Checking for a table row using DomCrawler

Tags: symfony, dom, phpunit, domcrawler

I am writing a phpunit test... on my page I have several rows, one of them is like this:

```
<tr><td>MATCH<small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></span></small></td></tr>
```

Some are like this:

```
<tr><td>NOT A MATCH 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>NOT A MATCH 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>NOT A MATCH 3</td></tr>
```

how can I run a test to check that the row with the pushpin glyphicon is the one with "MATCH"?

Basically I want the test to confirm that the glyphicon is appearing on the correct row, and just having something like `$crawler->filter('small:contains("' . $glyphCode . '")')->count()` only confirms that the glyph exists - not that it's in the right place.

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XPath Selectors with Symfony's DomCrawler.

To select your desired element use this XPath expression:

```
//td//small/span[@class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"]
```

Then place it inside a PHPUnit assertion.

```
$this->assertEquals(1, 
   $crawler->filterXPath('//td//small/span[@class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"]')->count()
);
```

I've used assertEquals 1 as expected value, to ensure that one element is found on the page.

Comment: Thanks. Using that along with `->parents()->parents()->html()` I was able to get what I needed. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the question can be treated as a string match problem.
There are several different ways to do that.

- use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find)

`$ret = $html->find('td[class=*glyph]');`

---

- use [regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) in PHP

the pattern string may like `/class="[^"]+glyph/`

---

- run **grep** command in the shell

`$ grep glyph xxx.php`